# How to set QIcon from an Url in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.7

I want to set my QIcon from an url which I am passing it as a string, but still it is not showing me any image, is there any other way to do it.

Comment: Download the image with QNetworkAccessManager, and then ask mr QIcon to display it?

Comment: Is Mr QIcon a singleton?

Comment: @chamber85 no it is not a singleton

Comment: @abhishek The joke's kind of lost now you edited your typo...

Comment: @chamber85 I think shobi is to blame here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **QNetworkAccessManager** to download image uring QUrl. You can use **QImageReader** to load image data to QImage.

[Here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/CS001431_-_Creating_an_HTTP_network_request_in_Qt) is nice example to demostrate this.

Comment: Is there no easier way? Nothing new with Qt5.2?